# Ipad/iphone..universal app

Tags: iphone, ipad

Hello I am creating universal app for iphone and i pad. I have table views and next views ..It is working fine in ipad but i want to add split view for ipad only.. how to do this in same code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create split view in MainWindow-iPad.xib and connect win your appdeletegate.

You need to check in appdelegate.h and .m file.

in .h file

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController;
SearchViewController *ipad_listViewController;
DetailResultViewController *ipad_detailViewController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISplitViewController *splitViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) SearchViewController *ipad_listViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) DetailResultViewController *ipad_detailViewController;
```

in .m file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    // Override point for customization after app launch    
    [self createDatabaseIfNeeded];

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        // Add the split view controller's view to the window and display.
        [window addSubview:splitViewController.view];
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
    else {
        [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: my first view is start page i want to add splitview for others ..I created window based app....my code is [self.window addSubview:startPage.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];  how to add this in splitview

Comment: i don't understand .. can you explain more detail some sample code on your question ?

Comment: my first view is simple view controller. I add this in appdelegate [self.window addSubview:startPage.view]; [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; and second view has tab bar controller and all other view are tableview controller with navigation.i want to add splitview for all view except first view..