# Can we develop single app for iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I’m new to iOS development and currently developing an app for iPhone and iPad.

My question is  can we develop single app that can run on both iPhone and iPad which match  their different screen sizes or resolutions . Or do I need to compile 2 different applications that match the different screen sizes or resolutions in iPad and iPhone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes we can! Universal app is the solution!

Read this blog : http://www.kotancode.com/2011/04/05/ios-universal-apps/

Comment: I cannot see any app on click of the above link

Answer (score 2):

We can develop single app to achieve this. Just select Device family as universal while creating new project. You will get option to prepare different Xib's for iphone and ipad. In code, you can either check for the device or use proper naming while allocating it.

For example,

For iphone -

```
oneViewController *oneView = [[oneViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"oneViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

For ipad - You can just use `"oneViewController~ipad"` as xib name. This will automatically load xib for ipad.

Answer (score 0):

you can make one universal app for both iPhone and iPad. Create different layout for both either using storyboard or nib files.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you don't need to compile 2 different applications that match the different screen sizes or resolutions in iPad and iPhone. There are already universal app in AppStore.
Try this:[Universal-iOS-App-Template](https://github.com/kwylez/Universal-iOS-App-Template) And this question:[iPad/iPhone universal app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430202/ipad-iphone-universal-app)